# wordpress tagcloud styling doesn't work

Tags: css, wordpress

Been messing with it for the past couple of hours. Trying to get a vertical space betweeb tags, but no luck...
Blog has a separate template file.

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/blog/

Html code

```
<div id="tagy">
widget code
</div>
```

css

```
#tagy {
margin-top: 20px !important;
}

#one h2 {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 45px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 26px !important;
color: #7e7e7e;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-color: #a6a6a6;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

 .seo-tag-cloud a {
margin: 10px;
padding: 7px;
background-color: #dddddd;
color: #666666;
font-size: 14px !important;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at your source and it seems like you have a spelling error: <div id="tegy">...</div>

Comment: nah. that's just tag id for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your `.seo-tag-cloud a` styling.  Anchors are inline by default, which means they don't have margin.

Comment: Two hrs of my life... At least something new learned... Tnx, man!